# How can I print string array in java when method toString doesnt work?

Tags: java

I try to print the list of accounts but they appear as @164552...
I tried to call the `toString` method like `Arrays.toString(accounts)` but it doesnt compile.

It complains about `static` and the that it can not resolve method `toString`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String personalNumber;
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    public Customer(String customerName, String customerSurname, 
                    String customerPersonalNumber) {
        this.name = customerName;
        this.surname = customerSurname;
        this.personalNumber = customerPersonalNumber;
        this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    }

    public Customer() {
    }

    public String getCustomerInfo() {
        return name + " " + surname + " " + personalNumber + accounts;
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Customer p = new Customer("Anna", "Larsson", "112323");
        p.addAccounts(new SavingsAccount());
        p.addAccounts(new SavingsAccount());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(accounts));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You have  no arrays in your code (beside `arg`). 2. `Arrays.toString` takes an array, not an `ArrayList`. 3. If you override `Object.toString` in `Account`, you would be able to see meaningful information by just printing using `System.out.println(accounts);`

Comment: Arrays.toString

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `toString` method in your Account class, then you can do :

```
System.out.println(accounts);
```